# Ionic 2 scroll down the page at page opening

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll, ionic2, ionic3

I'm doing a chat application. And when I open this chat application, I want the page to slide down.
When the box is in focus, the page slips down. But the page does not slip down when it first opens. What can I do ?
[Chat Page Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BASr3.png)
My Codes;

```js
ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.chat();
}
scrollToBottom() {
  if (this.content.scrollToBottom) {
     this.content.scrollToBottom();
  }
} 
onFocus() {
    this.content.resize();
    this.scrollToBottom();
    this.keyboard.show();
}
```

Comment: @suraj Okey, I added to answers. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used this property yet, but according to **[the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#input-properties)**:

```
Attr                Type        Details
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
scrollDownOnLoad    boolean     If true, the content will scroll down on load.
```

So you could do it like this:

```
<ion-content scrollDownOnLoad="true">
    <!-- ... -->
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I solved the problem**
I call down scroll function in HTML

```html
<ion-content no-padding>
    <div class="message-wrap" >
        <div *ngFor="let msg of gelenMesajlar; let i = index" class="message" [class.left]=" msg.GONDEREN === 'F' " [class.right]=" msg.GONDEREN === 'C' ">
            <div class="msg-detail">
                <div class="msg-content">
                    <span class="triangle"></span>
                    <span [style.font-size]="'10px'" *ngIf="msg.SIPARISID" [style.text-decoration]="'underline'">Konu #{{ msg.SIPARISID }} numaralı sipariş</span>
                    <p class="line-breaker">{{msg.MESAJ}}</p>
                    <span *ngIf="msg.SIPARISID" [style.font-size]="'12px'" (tap)="siparisGoruntule(msg.RESIMID, msg.SIPARISDURUMU, msg.SIPARISID)" [style.text-decoration]="'underline'">Siparişi Görüntüle</span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        {{ scrollToBottom() }}  <!-- Here it is-->
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Did this work perfectly for you? In my experience your `scrollToBottom` function should be called when all messages are rendered completely. Chances are there is a delay to load the messages, in which case `scrollToBottom` will run before the messages are rendered.

Comment: Of course, I have one more problem. With this code, when I load the messages and then slide the page upwards, it moves me down again. @Ari

Comment: @Degisim have you tried my answer? (I'm really curious since it's a relatively new property from the content component)

Comment: @sebaferreras I tried but I did not get a result :)

Comment: @Degisim: how do you make sure you don't scroll until all messages are loaded?